# Ordering attribute options on product page

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, swatches

We have a site with **a number of colour swatch options**. We have ordered the options in the attribute edit section but this does not seem to be taken into account when Magento renders the swatch options on the product page.

I have attached a couple of **screenshots** below. `Bone has been ordered before antique white but Antique White is displayed before Bone.` Is there a way to order these on the product page the way we want?

Magento version is 2.1.9.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Product attribute display based on added associated product to configurable product. Just sort those associated products of config product

Hope it will help.

Comment: Do you mean the order of how the attributes are displayed? I know this can be done but my question is how to set the order of the attributes values.

Comment: If your are talking about order of attribute value at front end then you have to remove simple products from config product and then add simple products based on order you want.

Comment: I don't know about this. For me simply saving a configurable product, even without making any changes to it, will throw the options into a seemingly random order